# setting a WCF service on a http when its already configured for https

Tags: wcf, http, https, firewall

We have a service on our 3rd party site which is configured to be invoked on a https (server to firewall and routing everything is configured for https)! Since We are unable to communicate with it due to certificate issue with DataPower on our side, we thought why not test the connectivity on http!

So now they trying to make the WCF Service as http on the same IP and port, they could see the Service not responding to inbound calls and ignoring the http request coming on a https configured IP + port!

I am not sure what can be done to say the .net WCF Service, hey ignore its on http and just get it rolling! They did disable https binding and just try with a http binding!

Any ideas would be great! Thanks!

(P.S. I dont have access to their code or config!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is IIS hosted or self hosted?

If it is hosted in IIS, then IIS needs to have the SSL certificate removed and the configuration set to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

In WCF, you would have to disable Transport security, which is usually in the configuration on the binding, like:

```
<binding>
  <security mode="Transport">
```

To disable HTTPS you would need to set `mode="None"` (or something other than Transport).

Comment: Yes its hosted by them through IIS! Thanks rally25rs, will check with them using ur inputs!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... Adding this to webconfig or appconfig of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```